# Error after adding constructor in partial entity class (Silverlight application)

Tags: c#, silverlight, service, ria

I have a problem!
I am developing silverlight application with ria services. When I added aditional constuctor in entity partial class, I can't initialize class object like:

```
select new VaultCashOrderQuantity
{
    VaultCashOrderQuantitiesId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    VaultCashOrderId = cashOrder.VaultCashOrderId,
    VaultCurrency = currency,
    VaultCurrencyCode = currency.VaultCurrencyCode,
    VaultCurrencyId = currency.VaultCurrencyId,
    VaultCurrencyDenomination = denomination,
    VaultCurrencyDenominationId = denomination.VaultCurrencyDenominationId,
    Denomination = denomination.Denomination,
    Quantity = 0,
    Summ = 0,
    Amount = 0,
})
```

Then I added parameterless constructor.Here my two new constructors in partial class:

```
public partial class VaultCashOrderQuantity
{
    public VaultCashOrderQuantity() { }
    public VaultCashOrderQuantity(CPCashOrderQuantity quantity, Guid cashOrderId)
    {
        VaultCashOrderQuantitiesId = Guid.NewGuid();
        VaultCashOrderId = cashOrderId;
        Denomination = quantity.Denomination;
        Quantity = quantity.Quantity;
        VaultCurrencyId = quantity.VaultCurrencyId;
        //VaultCurrency = quantity.VaultCurrency;
        VaultCurrencyDenominationId = quantity.VaultCurrencyDenominationId;
        //VaultCurrencyDenomination = quantity.VaultCurrencyDenomination;
        Summ = quantity.Summ;
        Amount = quantity.Amount;
    }
```

On application building I have got error message:

> *Type 'Vaults.Data.Models.VaultCashOrderQuantity' already defines a member called 'VaultCashOrderQuantity' with the same parameter types*

Why I'am getting this error message? How to fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the same example, but have you tryed to write your partial class without de default constructor?

Like this:

```
public partial class VaultCashOrderQuantity

{

    public VaultCashOrderQuantity(CPCashOrderQuantity quantity, Guid cashOrderId)
    {
        VaultCashOrderQuantitiesId = Guid.NewGuid();
        VaultCashOrderId = cashOrderId;
        Denomination = quantity.Denomination;
        Quantity = quantity.Quantity;
        VaultCurrencyId = quantity.VaultCurrencyId;
        //VaultCurrency = quantity.VaultCurrency;
        VaultCurrencyDenominationId = quantity.VaultCurrencyDenominationId;
        //VaultCurrencyDenomination = quantity.VaultCurrencyDenomination;
        Summ = quantity.Summ;
        Amount = quantity.Amount;
    }

}
```

If it does not work, maybe you could try to use this constructor in the ria service class.

In the last case, you could create a method and use it after the class initialization.

I cannot test it right now, that is why i am trying to help with these options, let me know what will happen.